permanent vnconfig OpenBSD?
I can manually mount a dd'ed image file (+fdisk, disklabel, newfs) with:
vnconfig vnd0 file.img
mount /dev/vnd0c /mnt/

Question: but where should I put the vnconfig command in OpenBSD?
I updated fstab to have the mount, but vnconfig is still a mistery, where should I put it? In a startup script?
